# How do I access my PC from the internet?

Tags: networking, home-networking, webserver, remote-access

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I configure my ADSL modem and Home PC to be able to access from external?](https://superuser.com/questions/6974/how-can-i-configure-my-adsl-modem-and-home-pc-to-be-able-to-access-from-external)

> **Other related questions:**
>   [How can a computer with dynamic IP work as a webserver?](https://superuser.com/questions/20580/how-can-a-computer-with-dynamic-ip-work-as-a-webserver)
>   [How can I make my home PC a web server?](https://superuser.com/questions/21931/how-can-i-make-my-home-pc-a-web-server)
>   [How to deploy my own computer as a web server?](https://superuser.com/questions/100230/how-to-deploy-my-own-computer-as-a-web-server)
>   [home webserver with blah.com domain](https://superuser.com/questions/66669/home-webserver-with-blah-com-domain)
>   [Make ubuntu Server Accesible to the Internet](https://superuser.com/questions/66619/make-ubuntu-server-accesible-to-the-internet)

I have a pc at home with a webserver and a linksys router. What do I need and how do I setup my pc so I can access my pc remotely and how to access a webpage on its webserver?

It's really a 2 part question.

1. How do I and what software do I need to access my pc remotely.
2. How do I access a webpage that is running on that same pc from outside my home network?

Comment: Since this is mostly a router configuration issue, please give us more details about your router, the model number, preferably.

Comment: dupe: http://superuser.com/questions/60324/access-my-pc-through-the-internet

Comment: @fretje - It is related, but not exact duplicate, I think. His ask is more simple than that, and only about his webserver, not about accessing to his computer's files, etc. in general. This question is more about "what to do on the router", step by step, in my opinion.

Comment: What program are you going to use to access your pc? Remote desktop, VPN?

Comment: @ivo:  From the question, I'd say browser to start with.

Comment: @Gnoupi: He asks "How do I setup my pc **so I can access my pc remotely** and how to access a webpage on its webserver". For that first question there you have a dupe, the other question is probably a dupe of another one.

Answer (score 3):

Go into your router and set up port forwarding for port 80 (or whatever port your server is set up to) so that requests from the Internet go to your computer's IP address internally.

Go to a site like "whatismyip.com" to see what your Internet-facing address is.

Then from an outside network, go to "http://youripaddress" and your web server's content should appear.

Same goes for remote access, forward the TCP port to your software's monitoring port (depends on what you're using; you don't mention it. If you're using VNC for example you'd use 5900 or 5800, depending on the configuration, or you would forward 22 for secure shell, etc.

Comment: or even better, `https://youripaddress`

Answer (score 1):

> How do I and what software do I need
>   to access my pc remotely.

I recommend **[TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/index.aspx)**, install TeamViewer Host as a Windows service on your home computer and use the TeamViewer Portable to access your computer from anywhere.

> How do I access a webpage that is
>   running on that same pc from outside
>   my home network?

If you have a static IP address at home, see [Bart Silverstrim's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/106688/how-do-i-access-my-pc-from-the-internet/106690#106690), if your IP address is assigned by DHCP (dynamically), use **[DynDNS](http://www.dyndns.com/)**.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest logmein.com

This is a quite simple application to install and really user-friendly. It's free!

[www.logmein.com](http://www.logmein.com)

Also, to access your router remotely, enable the remote assistance on it on port 8080 by example and then, you'll be able to manage it.

Comment: Read the question and not only the title. He wants to access only pages on his webserver.

Comment: plus, LogMeIn will install their own obnoxious display driver, wreaking havoc with Aero Glass ... use TeamViewer instead.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a good VPN. Grab your favorite Linux Distro, and install OpenVPN.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenVPN

This will let you connect to your network, and dial in to see what pages you want as if you were connected in the LAN

Answer (score 0):

If, like most people, your IP address may change, then a service like [DynDNS](http://www.dyndns.com/) will let you use a "proper" address rather than an IP address to get as far as your router.

As others have mentioned, you need to open a hole in your router to let you get through to the machine, to access the served web pages, you need to open port 80 and forward it to the machine with the server.

To get access to the machine as a user, you first need to get hold of a server that will allow you to log into the machine. Professional versions of Windows allow one to log in remotely but using a VPN is probably much, much safer. [Here](http://www.computernetworkinghelp.com/content/view/41/1/) is an article on setting one up in Windows XP using the built in stuff.